# Faster way to compress array of doubles

Tags: performance, compression

I am using code I found in another question to compress an array of doubles and then test the size. I do this a huge number of times. Can I make this code more efficient?

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] bytData)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Stream s = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress);
            s.Write(bytData, 0, bytData.Length);
            s.Close();
            byte[] compressedData = ms.ToArray();
            return compressedData;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    public List<double> B;
    while (true)
    {
       datum = getNewDatum();
       B.Insert(0, datum);
       if (B.Count > 500)
                B.RemoveAt(B.Count - 1);
       byte[] byteArray = B.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray();
       byte[] compressedData = Compress(byteArray);
       //Console.WriteLine(compressedData.Length);
    }
}
```

EDIT 1

Two areas might be able to be made faster:

1. The compression method.
2. How I am creating the byteArray in Main. Perhaps storing as a list of double and using SelectMany is not very efficient?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to optimization, I can propose a deterministic destruction and can rewrite as below,

```
 public static byte[] Compress(byte[] bytData)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var s = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    s.Write(bytData, 0, bytData.Length);
                    s.Close();
                    byte[] compressedData = ms.ToArray();
                    return compressedData;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with "using" - do you think this will cause less work when the function is called repeatedly?

Comment: The using statement implicitly call Dispose which essentially release resources used by that object. This is best practice when it comes to memory management. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Right - but s it likely to be slower? Does using "using" force Dispose to be call each time - whereas it is more intermittent the previous way?

Comment: I just benchmarked the "using" version against the original. Unfortunately, it did not yield any speed benefit

Comment: @ManInMoon, Deterministic destruction is not meant improve the speed rather effective resource (memory) utilization.